# Quadratic dynamical system (Solution to the Initial Value Problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm interested in a solution to the initial value problem of the following quadratic dynamical system with 2 states $\bigl(x(t), y(t)\bigl)$:

$$  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{dx}{dt} \\
    \frac{dy}{dt}\\
    \end{pmatrix} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
    x^2 \\
    y\\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
It would be a linear dynamical system if it were not for the quadratic term $x^2$ in the right hand side.

The form of the differential equation is analogous to the Riccati equation $y'=a+by+cy^{2}$ but generalized to a system of differential equations. I have seen that there is a matrix version of the Riccati equation but I haven't been able to put my problem into that form.

Is there an analytical solution (or approximation) to the initial value problem for such a quadratic dynamical system?

Comment: Let $x=\left( {{x}_{1}},{{x}_{2}} \right)=\left( x,y \right)$. Then your system can be put in the form:

$$ \dot{x}=Ax+uBx,\quad A=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0 & b  \\
   0 & d  \\
\end{matrix} \right],\quad B=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   a & 0  \\
   c & 0  \\
\end{matrix} \right] $$

where $u=x_1$. This is a _homogenous bilinear system_. Have you looked these up?

Comment: Couple of links I found [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/047134608X.W1003) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016769119390055B)...may not give you an explicit analytical solution but is a good starting point.